# Bolding across the site looks different for me?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

A few weeks ago I remember all the text across the site suddenly changed one day. Since then there are a lot of answers/questions that say "things in bold are...." but I don't see anything as bold? In fact, the text in questions and answers just looks strange to me. Is this just affecting me?

[image: What I See]

Comment: **THIS IS BOLD.** This is not.

Comment: It must only be my work computer. Everything looks fine on my laptop at home. Wonder what caused that then

Comment: @VanBuzzKill I assume you're running Windows - does your work computer have Helvetica font installed?

Comment: You know what, I think that's it. I needed to install it for a site we were working on. I'll be at work later today so I can post a picture today if needed.

Comment: @Jin Is there a way to fix this by disabling Helvetica font or something?

Comment: Hold Control, mousewheel scroll, and see if it goes away. Sometimes fonts don't work appear properly at certain resolutions or have quirks (like Bold being indistinguishable from normal text).

Answer (score 1):

[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

This is caused by a combination of things on your end, most likely fonts installed on your operating system, your browser's choice of rendering, and the zoom level of the page. The site has no control over these things. Zooming especially is [not supported by SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296008/179041).

For reference, the [font-family](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) of the site prefers *Arial*, then *"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica,* and finally any sans-serif font. So to address this locally, ensure:

- Your browser is up-to date
- You have *Arial* installed
- Your zoom level is set to 100%

Comment: Best font mode!